# How do i keep the space between elements the same when writing responsive CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

Good evening.
I've got three SVG files, consisting of 2 sleeves and a shirt-body.

[Shirt Layout with CSS-Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chBQh.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7hRS.png)

For the CSS-Grid attempt the SVG files are each placed in a div element, the second image shows the HTML posted below. The problem is that the elements move away from each other with growing screen sizes or move too close together and end up overlapping.[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tDXu.png) I've tried to use CSS Grid to position the elements, which worked out well but does not solve my problem since I cannot set negative gaps or margins for the grid. I've tried to work with % as well as vw and vh,  absolute and relative positioning but cannot make it work on every resolution so far.

```css
.containerShirt {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.shirtLeft {
  position: relative;
  height: 13%;
  left: 26.9%;
  bottom: 15vh;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  z-index: 2;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.shirtBody {
  position: relative;
  height: 40%;
  width: 35%;
  left: 13%;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  z-index: 1;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.shirtRight {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 24%;
  height: 13%;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 15vh;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  z-index: 1;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<div class="containerShirt">
  <svg class="shirtLeft"> ..... </svg>
  <svg class="shirtBody"> ..... </svg>
  <svg class="shirtRight">..... </svg>
</div>
```

Any ideas on what i could do? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

Read about that,
Or use min-width/ min-height

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-responsive-web-design-in-5-minutes/